# why there is onclick error?

Tags: android, onclick

In android studio, I have onclick error. My code are following,  MainActivity.java is following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void speakEnglish(View view) {

    int id = view.getId();
    String ourId = "";

    ourId = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName(id);

    String packageName = getPackageName();

    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(ourId, "raw", packageName);

    MediaPlayer mplayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resourceId);
    mplayer.start();


}
```

}

activity_main.xml code is following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.project.qinxin.learn.MainActivity">
<GridLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="speakEnglish"
        android:text="Button1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="speakEnglish"
        android:text="Button2"
        />

</GridLayout>
```

I cannot find problem for my code, it seems that function getRescources() and MainActivity are the problem. error message is here. When I click the botton, this app will stop. [image]

Comment: Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are hostile to those who use screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. Use the `{}` button to format any blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. **We can’t run your screenshot as code.**

Comment: I have post all my code, could you help me? @tadman

Comment: The `getIdentifier()` call is returning 0, which is an invalid resource ID, so `MediaPlayer.create()` throws. With the given layout, the value of `ourId` is going to end up being either `btn_1` or `btn_2`. Are those the names of the media files you have in `res/raw/`? It doesn't seem so, at least for one of them.

Comment: That is the problem, thanks a lot!@MikeM.

Comment: That looks a lot better. Thanks for fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that you are missing the following

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Comment: But there isn't a button with id button. Why I should add this line?@Marcus Mondel

Answer (score 0):

We need more details to answer precise answer to the question. Although errors such as `could not execute method for android onclick` often happens because of the body of the method. So `getResourceEntryName()` or `getIdentifier()` calls are a potential cause of this. please debug and see what values passed thru the calls. otherwise post more info to get better help

Comment: I have posted all the information, could you help me find the problem?@tatocaster